# Downgrade my level in Gears of war 3

Tags: gears-of-war-3

I have just started playing Gears of War 3 online, after a couple of games I reached rank 10. I think (though not quite sure) that reaching rank 10 moved me in to matches with better players.

I am getting shot in there in a split second. :-)

Is there a way to enter matches for beginners?

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is only two solutions for losing EXP in Gears of War 3.  This would be ally killing (negative score at end of game) and quitting games early.

For amusement, heres the chart for leveling:
http://forums.epicgames.com/threads/835392-Gears-of-War-3-Level-and-Exp-Chart

Reference
http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/991468-/61551273

Answer (score 0):

i have a much quicker solution, if you go to your xbox storage in the settings, go to gears of war 3, and delete the 'Player Data' file, it contains the data about youe multiplayer level and progress, however, you will also lose your wins, losses, kills, deaths, weapons stats etc from the Stats and Awards Page, so doing this wont be a massive bother for a lower level, but i wont recommend doing this if you are level 100 - 400 (Re-up)